# Restricting access of classes in Java

Tags: java, sdk

I'm writing an SDK in Java and I don't want every class to be accessible for the user to use.
**Making the class package-private doesn't help** because I have hundreds of classes that I want to order in different packages.
Is there any way to restrict a class access for users who use my code as a library? Or maybe make the IDE warn the user when he tries to use specific classes in the library?
Thanks!

EDIT: I just want the user to know somehow that a class is internal and is not supposed to be used by him. Documenting the class isn't enough.

Comment: Whilst not the answer you want I would strongly suggest making classes package private; this may require some re-engineering on your side. 
Your other options are (as stated below) java 9 module system, marking the classes with some form of annotation or plain and simple java doc. With package private it is still possible for users to access the code if they want to and I believe it is also possible to get around the module system for non-jdk  modules.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Java 9 at least, You can use `Modules` from JSR-376 standard. It's `JPMS (Java Platform Module System)`.

Package-private feature could be not enough for SKD, because Users can avoid this access type by reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare individual classes to be private or protected by using the "private" or "protected" access modifiers:

```
private class Classname {}
```

or

```
protected class Classname {}
```

More information: https://www.javatpoint.com/access-modifiers

Comment: As I said in my question, this solution isn't good enough because it forces me to put all of my classes in a single package.

Answer (score 0):

If you use at least java 9 You should use modules (jigsaw project) :

https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html

With module by default no public classes are exposed outside your library. You have to expose them `explicitly` via modules-info.java

example :

```java
module com.test {
    exports com.test.export;
}
```

Here you export explicity classes from package "export".